# Proof that while using projective representations on a vector, a phase will appear thus having a $1\mapsto e^{i\phi}$ mapping.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, transformation

I'm currently having a course about representation theory in the context of quantum mechanics and during the course, the professor said something about projective representations that I wasn't able to find elsewhere. He said that while using normal (i.e. non projective) representation, the corresponding transformation can be seen as a 1-1 mapping within the group. However, when projective presentations are used, the mapping becomes $1\mapsto e^{i\phi}$ and thus explaining the idea behind centrally extended groups.

Could someone send me a link where this kind of information is explained? I'm sorry for the lack of context but I don't have the notes and I couldn't find this information elsewhere.

Comment: I have found the answer in \url{https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/309459/nontrivial-phase-for-projective-so3-representation-simple-connectedness-and}, I hope it helps.

Comment: To display a link `link` with text `text`, use `[text](link)`.